# C# Selenium, how to check that text exists on page <div>

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation

I was wondering whether anyone is aware of a method to check that  text exists on a page, I have tried a few solutions, however sadly to no avail.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
    text I want to find<br>
    more text I want to find<br>                        
</div>
```

How do I confirm/assert that this is present? I'm assuming that `TagName` is involved? I am not sure however, I am at a very hello world level.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to find element with any text or particular text or verify element has some text??

Comment: It's difficult to suggest the best way to achieve this without any sample code or a bigger sample of your html, but looking into locators would be your best starting point [selenium locators](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators)

Comment: I basically received the answer from Cosmin, however I have a couple of extra questions if you don't mind looking below, I need all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the text is present inside your `div` tag, so you can just do:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("your_xpath"));
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Text))
{
    //the text is present
    //do your stuff here
}
```

EDIT to clarify the questions from the comment:
`string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return a boolean value: `true` if there's no value for the text (null or empty) and `false` if there are string characters in your text value. This includes whitespaces too, so if you want to make sure that you don't have a whitespaces only text you could also use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` that is a more deeper check than the previous one.
So, by reversing it using `!` (not operator) you're basically saying that if you have something in your text value, do other actions.

Now, to assert that the text is indeed the correct one, you use the `Text` property of the `IWebElement` interface, property that contains the text value between the opening and closing of your html tag.
In code this would translate to:

```
//exact text
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("your_xpath"));
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Text) && element.Text == "your_text") 
{
    //the text is present
    //do your stuff here
}

//partial text
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("your_xpath"));
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Text) && element.Text.Contains("your_text"))
{
    //the text is present
    //do your stuff here
}
```

You need to preserve the order in your `if` statement because if the text value is `null`, when you're applying `Contains()` on it, it will result in a `Object reference exception.`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can confirm this did indeed work. I have a couple of questions:
One is more clarification based - the '!' before string basically means 'not'?  Say I take the '!' away it would expect it to be empty, or not present, however am I basically reversing that? (I am learning all of this and want to fully understand).
Second, is there anyway to confirm whether the text is one that I want/need, ideally I would be able to select a part of it and verify that it's present.

Once again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for this in-depth explanation, as someone new to not only automation, but testing in general this helped me understand how this statement works and I'll be able to do loads more automation with this!

Comment: Hello, another question, I just did it with this element, and I cannot get it to go through the loop, it seems to pass, but it doesn't do what I ask it to do in the case that it does pass, which is close the browser, so I'm assuming it's not going through the loop.

        <font id="feedbackMessage" style="display: none;" color="red">
      Incorrect details, or account has expired.
      </font>
       xpath
//*[@id="feedbackMessage"]

Comment: Hello, nevermind, it was executing the statement straight away which meant it didn't work, I just put a 5 second delay on using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);